# Как обработать path-параметры?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, http-status-code-404, error404

Пишу API на Django REST framework.
Допустим, есть такой url: api/category//?product=product&param1=param1/

Здесь `id` - это идентификатор записи в модели `Product`.
`product`, `param2` и т.п. - это path-параметры, которые могут быть переданы, а могут и не быть.
По факту `product = ForeignKey('Category')`.
`param1` - тут разные параметры, в частности, это может быть поле модели `Product`.

Вьюха возвращает `queryset` из `Category`. Если объект не найден, то должна быть ошибка 404.
Если `id` категории передан неверно (неверный формат, несуществующий id), то тоже возвращаем 404. Если `id` передан верно, но у него неправильно указан или отсутствует product, то тоже 404.

Сейчас в случае таких ошибок возвращается ошибка 500.

Собственно вопрос. Как обрабатывать входящие параметры?

Я могу их вытащить из url например, так:

```
id_param = self.kwargs.get('id')
param1 = params1.get('param1', None)
```

Далее делаю примерно так:

```
try:
   queryset = queryset = Category.objects.get(id=id_param)
except:
   content = {'Объект не найден': 'Значение {} имеет неверный формат'.format(id_param)}
   return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

И единственная мысль - проверять каждый параметр последовательно. То есть сначала получаю категорию. Если ее нет, то выбрасываю исключение 404. Если она есть, то для нее проверяю продукт. Если его нет, то выбрасываю исключение 404. И так далее, последовательно по всем параметрам, пока не сформирую искомый `queryset`.

Но правильно ли я делаю? Уверен, есть куда более элегантное решение. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что вы пытаетесь создать функционал, который уже существует. Конкретно для `drf` вы можете найти фильтрацию по паратетрам [здесь](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/).

И в документации по `django` вы можете найти метод [get-object-or-404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), который дает возможность избегать написание исключений типа `DoesNotExist`.

Данный метод может принимать входным аргументом `QuerySet` основанным на фильтре или цепочке фильтров, если параметров в строке больше одного.

UPD

По просьбе из комментария добавлю вывод для exception (взято из документации)

```py
try:
   queryset = queryset = Category.objects.get(id=id_param)
except Exception as inst:
   content = {'status': 'exception', 'message': inst}
...
""" пример-пояснение из документации
except Exception as inst:
    print(type(inst))    # the exception instance
    print(inst.args)     # arguments stored in .args
    print(inst)          # __str__ allows args to be printed directly,
                         # but may be overridden in exception subclasses
"""
```

Comment: Забыл написать, что мне с ошибкой 404 надо возвращать текст с причиной ошибки. Про фильтры я помню, но там вроде нет подобного функционала? То есть если неправильно указан id категории, то вывожу 404 - текст "Объект не найден. Неверно указан id". Если неверный параметр param1, то 404 - объект не найден, проверьте параметр param1. Чтобы пользователь не гадал, что он не так ввел.

Comment: Так я так и делаю )) Но мне не нравится та простыня, которая сейчас получается. В первом блоке try-except я получаю Category.objects.get(id=id), если не нахожу, то выбрасываю 404 ошибку. Так как если нет категории, то проверять продукты в ней уже нет смысла. В следующем блоке try-except я проверяю Product.objects.filter(category=категории, найденной на предыдущем шаге). Если нет результата, то 404 ошибка. И так по всем параметрам. Есть ли в DRF более совершенный механизм? ))

Comment: Для ответа json. В классе наследуюсь от generics.ListAPIView. В функции get() данного класса обрабатываю параметры вышеуказанным способом и если они корректны получаю итоговый queryset, который передаю в сериализатор, наследуемый от ModelSerializer. В сериализаторе всего три строки: class Meta: model = модель, fields = выводимые поля.

Comment: Попробую объяснить подробнее. Вот есть url: api/category/id/?product=product&param1=param1/, где id - это параметр, идентификатор категории; product - это параметр, допустим идентификатор продукта. И т.д. Допустим, что я указал идентификатор категории, которого в базе нет. Следовательно, и продуктов для него нет. А значит запрос по такому некорректному адресу вернет ошибку 500 Server Error. Мне же надо вместо нее вернуть ошибку 404 и описание, из-за чего ошибка. Вот и приходится обрабатывать последовательно каждый параметр, чтобы просто выводить причину ошибки.

Comment: Вместо этого я бы мог сразу получить нужный queryset = Model.objects.filter(параметры). И именно его  обрабатывать в блоке try-except. Но в этом случае я бы смог вывести только общий текст типа: Response(status=404, content = "Объект не найден"). А вот из-за какого параметра объект не найден, что нужно исправить, здесь же указать не получится. Вот и приходится перед этим плодить блоки try-except, обрабатывая по одному параметру перед получением искомого queryset'а. Это и напрягает.

Comment: Имеете ввиду запрос вида Model.objects.filter(параметры).filter(параметры).filter(параметры)? А можете дать пример, как отправлять сообщение из exception? Возможно, я что-то подобное видел, но соображалка сегодня уже устала )))

Comment: Спасибо! В целом, я так примерно и делаю. Вычисляю queryset, затем на его основе следующий. А ответ я добавляю так. Пример: try:
            queryset = здесь запрос
        except:
            content = {'Объект не найден': 'Значение {} имеет неверный формат даты. '.format(param)}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

Comment: Про формат даты, есть такое понятие, как валидация. Есть уже написанные инструменты для работы с этим, можно кастомизировать и сделать доступными любые форматы дат, для удобства использования и меньшего числа обращений недовольных клиентов API

Comment: @Артур я удалю верхние комментарии, не очень хорошо иметь такие пространственные рассуждения в комментах

Comment: Хорошо. Про формат даты - это я для примера просто привел. Про валидацию мне ясно, но пока задача имеет общий характер - обработать queryset и вернуть или его, или код ошибки. Благодарю за помощь!